# C# Pascal Triangle Code doesn't work - Logic correct

Tags: c#

I've been trying to learn more about C#, and so I was doing a little practicing with Lists:

```
static void Main()
    {
        List<List<int>> a = new List<List<int>>();
        List<int> temp = new List<int>();
        temp.Add(1);
        a.Add(temp);
        for (int i = 0; i < 9; i++)
        {
            temp.Clear();
            temp.Add(1);
            for (int q = 0; q < a[i].Count-1; q++)
            {
                temp.Add(a[i][q] + a[i][q+1]);
            }
            temp.Add(1);
            a.Add(temp);
        }
        foreach (var i in a[8])
            Console.Write(i + " ");
        Console.WriteLine();
    }
```

I converted this to C++, and it works perfectly. However, in C#, a[i].Count is *always* 1. Even though after the first loop the size must be 2.

My only guess is that there's some major difference between C++'s Vector and C#'s List that I've apparently missed. Any ideas?

Here's the C++ code which works:

```
int main()
{
    std::vector<std::vector<int>> a;
    std::vector<int> b;
    b.push_back(1);
    a.push_back(b);
    for (int i = 0; i < 9; i++)
    {
        b.clear();
        b.push_back(1);
        for (int q = 0; q < a[i].size()-1; q++)
        {
            b.push_back(a[i][q] + a[i][q+1]);
        }
        b.push_back(1);
        a.push_back(b);
    }
    for (auto i : a[8])
    {
        std::cout << i << ' ';
    }
}
```

Output for C++ Code:

1 8 28 56 70 56 28 8 1

Output For C# Code:

1 1

Any help is appreciated, thanks!

Comment: In your C++, you're iterating the 8th index. In C# the 0 index.

Comment: *Code doesn't work - Logic correct* bit of a problem in that statement.

Comment: @John  Sorry, it was just from testing. The 8th index gives the same output.

Comment: @user4581301 What's wrong with the statement? The logic of the code works, the implementation is faulty - hence why I'm here!

Comment: If you are a C++ programmer, you need to think of C# reference-type variables as if they were pointers (that magically delete themselves after they are no longer used-not via RAII, via garbage collection) . Code like `var a = new MyType(); var b = a;` results in two variables of type `MyType` that both reference (effectively *point to*) the same object on the *managed heap*. Don't try to map STL concepts too closely to C# concepts.

Comment: @Flydog57 Thanks for the advice. I should have realized it since I was using "new", but I just had the idea in my head that it was equivalent to a vector.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Look at your C# code `a.Add(temp);`. This `temp` variable is a reference type, so it will always add the same memory object.

To fix that, you can use LINQ to solve it:
`a.Add(temp.ToList());`. `ToList()` will generate a new object with different memory.

Comment: Thanks a lot! That fixed it. I'll have to look into that more.

Answer (score 1):

I have modified your code slightly, the main difference to not is, C# there are mainly 2
kind of types, one is a reference type and one is a value type.
List is a reference type.
In your code, you always clearing and adding numbers to the temp list.
that always points to the same object, so when you clear in the nth row, it's also clearing all the rows before it.

```
    List<List<int>> a = new List<List<int>>();

    a.Add(new List<int> { 1 });
    for (int i = 0; i < 9; i++)
    {
        List<int> temp = new List<int>();
        temp.Add(1);
        for (int q = 0; q < a[i].Count - 1; q++)
        {
            temp.Add(a[i][q] + a[i][q + 1]);
        }
        temp.Add(1);
        a.Add(temp);
    }
    foreach (var row in a)
    {
        foreach (var col in row)
        {
            Console.Write(col + " ");
        }

        Console.WriteLine();
    }

    Console.ReadKey();
```

Comment: Thanks, that cleared it up! A rookie mistake on my part.